# Evaluating robust estimators performance on various datasets

Tags: robust, estimators

**To sum up the question:** is there some recommended set of datasets or should I put the list together myself from articles on robust estimators?

If I wanted to test performance of different robust estimators, what are the various datasets that are frequently used? I am interested in both simulated and real datasets that I could use. It seems impractical to have to simulate various scenarios on my own and also it might not be very useful to pick real datasets at random.

I am interested in a set of datasets which would allow me to empirically find scenarios under which various robust estimators (LTS, LWS, WLS, S estimators, S-weighted estimators) break down.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to compare performances of different estimators, you should simulate your datasets. This way, you are in control of the settings, and you can create harder/easier scenarios to compare the performance of the different estimators. Furthermore, you'll know what a good estimate should look like, since you simulated the data and chose the true parameter value.

There a few ways you can simulate datasets with outliers and extreme observations. 1) Simulate from a normal distribution with large variance. 2) Simulate from a t-distribution with low degrees of freedom. 3) Simulate from any distribution under "normal" settings and artificially add in extreme observations. You can also look into other heavy-tailed distributions such as Laplace distribution (also known as double exponential). You can always plot a histogram of the data to get a quick visual on how spread out the data is and how extreme are the outliers.